# In mvc, how do I get responses when using form-based model binding versus javascript serialization?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I created a form in MVC originally using javascript serialization and jQuery to $.post() to the controller method.  This was working fine except a single field wasn't being bound to a method argument for some reason so I switched to the MVC built-in model binding instead which fixed this issue.  The result of this, though, is that I'm cut off from my response messages.  My validation messages still show up fine but things like "alert('saved')" don't work and I can't figure out how to do other things like conditionally refresh the page and such.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

The jQuery code was:

```
        $.post(
        'controllerURL',
        {
            IRN: irn,
            SepId: sepId,
            JvsId: jvsId,
            From: from,
            To: to,
            Notes: notes,
            CTA: cta
        },
        function (data) {
            if(data.Success == null) {
                alert(data.Error);
                return;
            }

            alert(data.Success);
            reloadPage();
        },
        'json'
    );
```

And the controller method looks like such:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateJvsEntry(JVSDataEntryModel model) //(string IRN, int SepId, int? JvsId, DateTime From, DateTime? To, string Notes, int CTA)
    {
        if (model.To.HasValue && model.To.Value < model.From)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "To can not be prior to From.");
            //return Json(new { Error = "To can not be prior to From." });
        }

        var entry = new EmisJvs();

        if (model.JvsEntryId > 0)
        {
            entry = _jvsDataService.GetWhere(w => w.JvsId == model.JvsEntryId && w.SEPID == model.SepId).Single();
        }
        else
        {
            if (DoesJvsHaveOpenEntries(model.SepId))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "You must close out the current JVS entry before creating a new one.");
                //return Json(new { Error = "You must close out the current JVS entry before creating a new one." });
            }

            entry.SEPID = model.SepId;
        }

        entry.SchoolIRN = model.SchoolIRN;
        entry.From = model.From;
        entry.To = model.To;
        entry.Notes = model.Notes ?? string.Empty;
        entry.Percentage = model.CTA;
        entry.ChangedOn = DateTime.Now;
        entry.ChangedBy = _userService.CurrentUser().SepId;

        if (model.JvsEntryId == 0)
        {
            _jvsDataService.Insert(entry);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _jvsDataService.SaveChanges(entry);
        }

        return View("JVSDataEntry", model);
    }
```

Another Edit:

I ended up going back to the $.post() solution that I was doing before.  Going the model-binding route through native MVC forms is not agreeing with the current project architecture I'm working with and I was just running in circles so I just backed up and applied KISS.  The original issue that caused me to investigate model-binding has to do with an oddity either on the page or within jQuery itself.  I can verify an element with id "Notes" exist on the page but when I do `$('#Notes').val()` I was getting nothing returned even though text was indeed in the input box.  I ended up having to do the long-form cascade style selectors and `$('div[class=\'jvsDataEntryDiv\'] input[id=\'Notes\']').val()` works instead.

Thanks, Jesse, and everyone else.

Comment: k.. u can paste u r jquery and mvc code here?

Answer (score 1):

Your client side messages are not working as you are returning a view from your post. If you want to handle the refresh client side then you should probably return some form of json result:

```
return new JsonResult
{
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    Data = new { Success = "Some success message here" }
};
```

**EDIT**:
As per your comment, I don't believe your jQuery $.post function is setup correctly. Try adding the following:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: The issue I was experiencing returning Json was that the browser (IE 9) was treating the response as a file download which contained the Json string instead of the Json object being passed to some javascript method in my view.

Comment: @Mikie see my edit, it doesn't look like you are setting the content type of the $.post which might by why ie opening the file download dialog.

Comment: Edited OP.  I didn't use your advice but I must not have explained the original issue well enough as your response tells me you didn't get what I was trying to say, which isn't your fault.  Thanks anyway!